# How many times a component render before display?

Tags: reactjs

When I read the document for the useEffect the component will render only one time if I recall correctly.

But in the bottom scenario the `initial render is empty`.
But after a sec or two `it will render again to show that data coming from api`.

So it basically render two times before showing the data am I wrong?

```
const SomeComponent = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('...').then((res) => setData(res.data)).catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>{data.map((e) => (e...)}</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: component will re render each time any internal state changes which you are doing by updating state using `setData`. It also re render if parent component re renders.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is possibly from [`React.StrictMode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:...

Well, it's helpful in debugging during development but this side effect makes `useEffect` called twice intentionally.

*One side note is these double callings won't be happening in production, so you don't need to worry about it.*

If you want to avoid *intentionally double-invoking* in development, you can remove `React.StrictMode` permanently in your code.